# Angularjs returning dummy promise from function that have no data to return?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

So I have function that clear/delete some data.

No errors to return. No data to return (it should not exists by the time function reach return).

Code that need promise:

```
SomeService.close().then(
  function onSuccess() {
```

**How do I return something usefull from close() that .then can work with?**

```
//In SomeService
function close(){
 delete that;
 delete those;
 delete etc;
 return $q.defer().resolve().promise;
}
```

Will give me following error:

```
$q.defer(...).resolve(...) is undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit wrong, try:

```
function close(){
  delete that;
  delete those;
  delete etc;
  return $q.resolve();
}
```

Comment: So resolve do not return this? Its crazy. :( My oneliner now become 3-liner.

Comment: You can also do `return $q.resolve()` .. forgot about that :)

Comment: `return $q.resolve();` --> `Error: $q.resolve is not a function`

Comment: $q.resolve() is not defined in Angular 1.3.x which I use. But its correct answer non the less.

Answer (score 3):

You can use $q.when for that purpose.

```
function close(){
  delete that;
  delete those;
  delete etc;
  return $q.when();
}
```

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able
>   promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an
>   object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes
>   from a source that can't be trusted.